# "Search Work Items" inactive in Visual Studio Team Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, version-control

My "Search Work Items" window in VS 2015 Team Explorer is not active, and I cannot bring it to life. Any ideas?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

After opening Visual Studio, open any solution which is bound to TFS and then you should be able to see that Box enabled.